# List of common and uncommon categories

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

I want to learn more about the category of "super commutative" graded $k$-algebra, for instance, its coproduct. However, I couldn't find anything related material.

So, am I be able to get access to a book that discuss "all" kind of categories?

Answer (score 4):

The coproduct is a super version of the tensor product (which is the coproduct in commutative $k$-algebras); its graded pieces are

$$(A \otimes B)_k = \bigoplus_{i+j=k} A_i \otimes B_j$$

with multiplication

$$(a_1 \otimes b_1)(a_2 \otimes b_2) = (-1)^{|b_1| |a_2|} a_1 a_2 \otimes b_1 b_2.$$

This is the relevant notion of tensor product for describing the cup product on the product of two spaces via the Kunneth formula.